# I don't know how to run a program from terminal involving NLTK. All the examples are run from the interpreter but don't use actual programs

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to run a program that uses NLTK.  In the NLTK book it uses the interpreter to run individual scripts such as this

```
>>> import nltk
```

My program is similar but I want to run it from a file

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

mytext = "Hello Adam how are you? I hope everything is good"

print(sent_tokenize(mytext))`
```

I get this error message

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Beowulf\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\nltk.py", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "C:\Users\Beowulf\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\nltk.py", line 2, in <module>
    from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk.tokenize'; 'nltk' is not a package
```

I am using PyCharm

I want to save the file and run the file from the command line.

Comment: looks like you didn't install `nltk`. Start [here](https://www.nltk.org/install.html). Also, it looks like your py file is called `nltk`. Do not do this, give it a name that isn't the same as the module you're trying to import. I think these two things combined generate the exact error you're seeing...

Comment: Does `from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize` work from "the interpreter" (aka REPL - Read-Eval-Print-Loop)?

Comment: Yes tokenizer works from interpreter

Comment: Edo Akse/ ForceBru, I did manage to get it to run now Thanks!